# How to replace NULL with white space in Azure Data Factory for all data types?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have columns of different data types. For example, some column has int type, other is date and another is string type.

When I use `iifNull(column1, ' ')`
it works only for string data type.

Moreover, when I have date column and I use as below code, the result is still NULL

```
iifNull(datecol, toTimestamp('1990-01-01', 'yyy-MM-dd'))
```

1. How to replace integer and date columns NULL values with white space then?
2. How to work with date column?

Comment: You'd have to cast the columns to strings if you wanted to store a space. In Data flows, NULL is no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your coming data is csv file and with different column type, I tested and it works well, Please see the example bellow:

**Derived Column expressions and output:**

```
iifNull(id, ' ')
iifNull({ name}, ' ')
iifNull({ dd}, ' ')
```

[image]

If your coming data is from SQL database table, we must convert the `int` or `date` column to string data type, then run the `iifNull()` function.

Ref this example:

**SQL database source:**
[image]

**Derived Column expressions and output:**

```
iifNull(toString(id), ' ')
iifNull(name, ' ')
iifNull(toString(dd), ' ')
```

[image]

HTP.

Comment: What about in the case of not using 'Data Flows', for example when implementing a dynamic condition when setting a variable value.